# spring controller test by mock service

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, junit, mockito

Love Spring Testing Even More With Mocking and Unit Test Assistant:

A mocked service replaces multiple dependencies

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvUzB.png)

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/people")
public class PeopleController {
    @Autowired
    protected PersonService personService;
    @GetMapping
    public ModelAndView people(Model model) {
        for (Person person: personService.getAllPeople()) {
            model.addAttribute(person.getName(), person.getAge());
        }
        return new ModelAndView("people.jsp", model.asMap());
    }
}
```

private MockMvc mockMvc:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class PeopleControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    PersonService personService;

    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Configuration
    static class Config {
        // Other beans
        @Bean
        public PersonService getPersonService() {
            return mock(PersonService.class);
        }
    }
    @Test
    public void testPeople() throws Exception {
        // When
        ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(get("/people"));
    }
}
```

I get a mistake when I want to run `mockMvc`

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: What is `mockMvc` ?

Comment: @Ravi Main entry point for server-side Spring MVC test

Comment: can you share this class ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Perform the following steps:

1. create service mock instead of service original
   ("PersonServiceMock")
2. replace service original by service mock

   ```
       @Autowired
       PersonService personService;

       @Autowired
       PeopleController peopleController;

       private MockMvc mockMvc;

       @Before
       public void setup() {
       peopleController = new PeopleController(new personServiceMock());
       mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(peopleController).build();
      }    

       @Configuration
       static class Config {
           // Other beans
           @Bean
           public PersonService getPersonService() {
               return mock(PersonService.class);
           }
       }
       @Test
       public void testPeople() throws Exception {
           // When
           ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(get("/people"));
       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are never initialising `mockMvc` in your code and the point where you access it results in `nullPointerException`. You need to initialise it before using it, and since multiple tests in your class could be using it, best place to do it is `setup()` method annotated with `@before`. Try below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration
public class PeopleControllerTest {
@Autowired
PersonService personService;

@Autowired
private WebApplicationContext wac;

private MockMvc mockMvc;

@Before
public void setup() {
  mockMvc = MockMvcBuilders.webAppContextSetup(wac).build();


@Configuration
static class Config {
    // Other beans
    @Bean
    public PersonService getPersonService() {
        return mock(PersonService.class);
    }
}
@Test
public void testPeople() throws Exception {
    // When
    ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(get("/people"));
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

from the source code I see that the mockMvc doesn't have any value, thats why it hits "java.lang.NullPointerException" for this line of code :

```
ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(get("/people"));
```

to make it run, I think need to give value to mockMvc first. 
by constructor :

```
@Test
public void testPeople() throws Exception {
    mockMvc = new MockMvc();
    // When
    ResultActions actions = mockMvc.perform(get("/people"));
}
```

or Autowired :

```
@Autowired
MockMvc mockMvc
```

depends on the purpose of MockMvc Class